# snap-to-road returns empty response

Tags: google-maps, google-roads-api

I'm referring to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#example_request) API

I'm getting **empty** response from the API. There is no error, just `{}` in the response, instead of `"snappedPoints"`

What does it mean ?

Where can I find the documentation about errors ?
Some errors have helpful message like `too many points` or `invalid API key`

Here is the exact URL - you can put this into the browser address bar and see for yourself. (You'll need to use your own API key though)

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=12.9225471,77.6711921|12.9225471,77.6711921|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225665,77.6711702&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Using `interpolate=true` did not help (i.e. still `{}` in the response)

Comment: You repeat `12.9225471,77.6711921` for the first two coordinates.  Then you repeat `12.9225468,77.6711909` for the next seven coordinates.  It'd probably be wiser to eliminate all duplicates; it's more likely to work properly.  Try `https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=12.9225471,77.6711921|12.9225468,77.6711909|12.9225665,77.6711702&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: There are no roads near there, the points are all in the middle of an apartment complex (Akme Harmony Apartments).

Comment: Removing duplicates (the URL you suggested with my API_KEY) also returns empty response just ``{}``

Answer (score 0):

The issue here with coordinates. Please see working example:
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=60.170880,24.942795|60.170879,24.942796|60.170877,24.942796&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Also similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058485/2604529)