# Google Road Api SnapToRoad golang

Tags: google-maps, go, google-roads-api

I was trying to implement google's **snaptoroad**  api. But I am not getting any output. I am using golang for the implementation. My Code is as follows:

```
mapClient, err := maps.NewClient(maps.WithAPIKey(GoogleApiServerKey))
if err != nil{
    log.Println(err)
}

//Input
latlng := maps.LatLng{}
path := []maps.LatLng{}
latlng.Lat = 9.7162348
latlng.Lng = 76.6702793
path = append(path, latlng)
latlng.Lat = 9.7162400
latlng.Lng = 76.715195
path = append(path, latlng)
latlng.Lat = 9.7162410
latlng.Lng = 76.7759261
path = append(path, latlng)

inputRequest := &maps.SnapToRoadRequest{
    Path: path,
}

outputResponse, err := mapClient.SnapToRoad(context.Background(), inputRequest)

fmt.Println(outputResponse)
pretty.Println(outputResponse)
```

The Output this code produces are

```
&{[]}
&maps.SnapToRoadResponse{}
```

Blank output is returned. Anyone please point out the mistake I made here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your err first.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Thanks for the reply bro. But there are no errors.. I checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, but It seems that your API Key is not activated. 
Please visit [googleAPI dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) 
to enable it.

You can always check it working:
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=60.170880,24.942795|60.170879,24.942796|60.170877,24.942796&key=YOUR_API_KEY

the output would be:

```
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 60.170877918672588,
        "longitude": 24.942699821922421
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJNX9BrM0LkkYRIM-cQg265e8"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 60.170876898776406,
        "longitude": 24.942699912064775
      },
      "originalIndex": 1,
      "placeId": "ChIJNX9BrM0LkkYRIM-cQg265e8"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 60.170874902634374,
        "longitude": 24.942700088491474
      },
      "originalIndex": 2,
      "placeId": "ChIJNX9BrM0LkkYRIM-cQg265e8"
    }
  ]
}
```